# Drill SQL was executed successfully when the ports were wrong

Tags: java, database, jdbc, apache-drill

I use `SimpleDriverDataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` to connect to my drill server. In order to make this connection successful, I have to set the correct jdbcUrl. The problem is, I can set the drill server's port to any number, even larger than 65535, and the result is correct every time. I don't know why. Here's my code.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestDrill {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestDrill.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:drill:drillbit=server1:66666,server2:66666,server3:66666";
        SimpleDriverDataSource drillDs = new SimpleDriverDataSource(driver, jdbcUrl, "username", "password");
        JdbcTemplate drillTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(drillDs);
        try {
            List<Map<String, Object>> dbs = drillTemplate.queryForList("show schemas");
            logger.debug(dbs.toString());
            logger.debug("show schemas succeeded");
        } catch(DataAccessException e) {
            logger.debug("show schemas failed");
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If I set the wrong server hostname, the query would fail. This is normal. I just have no idea why I can set any port number and the query would still be successful.

Comment: Generally all bigdata eco systems are like, when it doesn't found a connection in one port it check next 10/100 ports. I observed that in hive & spark. might be that issue, but if with any port it connecting, we need to see.